# Get current url query string

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

I'm trying to write a handlebars helper that spits out the current url query string. I will then use that query string to populate a template. I'm using assemble to do the html file generation.

My urls look like this: `groups/group-details/?id=1` and I want to get at the id value.

Here is my helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentId', function() {
    return document.location.search.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
});
```

And I am calling it in my .hbs template like this:

```
{{currentId}}
```

I am expecting it to just spit out `1` in this example but nothing is shown.

Where am I going wrong?

**- Edit -**

Digging around in the web inspector console shows my helper is registered but if I put a breakpoint on the return statement, it never gets hit. I assume the helper just isn't being 'executed'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating the html with assemble, then assemble is doing a render pass with Handlebars. This render pass would try to resolve the `{{currentId}}` template on the server.

If it's doing that, I would expect an error inside the helper since `document.location.search` is not available. Since you aren't getting an error there, I'm assuming that the helper isn't registered with assemble and only with your front-end instance of Handlebars. If it's not registered with assemble, then `{{currentId}}` is interpreted as a value by Handlebars and renders nothing.

TL;DR;

When mixing front-end templates and backend templates, you need to escape the front-end templates so the backend process doesn't render them. Try using `\{{currentId}}` to see if the helper is used.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying. Putting in `\{{currentId}}` just outputs `{{currentId}}` in the generated html.

Comment: Are you rendering templates in the browser too? If not, then I don't think `document` will be available on the server so there isn't a query string at that time.

Comment: I'm not, no. What you're saying about the query string makes perfect sense. I will have to change my approach and render templates for that set of pages in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you are going wrong.

But, I would use a regex here.

for parsing `1` out of `groups/group-details/?id=1`

```
var a =  (new RegExp('/?id=(\d)+'));
var v = a.exec('groups/group-details/?id=1')[1];
console.log(v);
```

Also, I tried out

`"groups/group-details/?id=1".split('?')[1].split('=')[1]`

and it returns `1` fine.

The reason why i would go with regex is you are already doing two string manipulations which might not be most efficient way.